# Hibernate Criteria INNER join on many-to-many always empty

Tags: hibernate, many-to-many, inner-join

I use Hibernate 3.2.1.GA and have a many-to-many mapping between Condition and ContextParameterValue. When I create a Criteria query and join Condition and ContextParameterValue together with an **INNER_JOIN**, the ContextParameterValue collection on Condition stays empty. When I change it to **LEFT_JOIN**, the ContextParameterValue collection has 3 elements, as expected, because there are 3 relevant records in the join table for the query.

Condition and ContextParamaterValue (the relevant parts):

```
class Condition {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "CONDITION_SEQ")
  private Long conditionId;

  @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  @JoinTable(name = "CONDITION_TO_PARAMVALUE", uniqueConstraints =      {@UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"CONDITIONID", "CONTEXTPARAMETERVALUEID" }) } ,
                joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "CONDITIONID", nullable = false), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "CONTEXTPARAMETERVALUEID", nullable = false))
  private Set<ContextParameterValue> comparisonValues = new HashSet<ContextParameterValue>();
}


class ContextParameterValue {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "CONTEXT_PARAMETER_VALUE_SEQ")
  private Long contextParameterValueId;

  @ManyToMany(targetEntity = Condition.class, mappedBy = "comparisonValues")
  private Set<Condition> conditions = new HashSet<Condition>();
}
```

The ContextParameterValue collection on Conditition is called "comparisonValues" and it is **INNER_JOIN** -ed in the query below:

```
Criteria criteria = getSession().createCriteria(Rule.class, "rule");
criteria.createAlias("conditions", "condition", Criteria.LEFT_JOIN)
    .createAlias("condition.contextParameter", "contextParameter", Criteria.INNER_JOIN)
    .createAlias("condition.operator", "operator", Criteria.INNER_JOIN)
    // INNER JOINING comparisonValues below!
    .createAlias("condition.comparisonValues", "comparisonValues", Criteria.INNER_JOIN) 
    .createAlias("contextParameter.fieldDataType", "fieldDataType", Criteria.INNER_JOIN)
    .createAlias("contextParameter.contextParameterValues", "contextParameterValue", Criteria.LEFT_JOIN)
    .setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY);
criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("rule.paymentMethod", paymentMethod));
criteria.addOrder(Order.asc("rule.name"));
return criteria.list();
```

Inner joining the comparisonValues results in an empty collection:

[image]

There are records present in the join table that ties ContextParametersValues to Conditions.

Also, I can see in the log that the correct query is generated by Hibernate. When I run the query against the database myself (Oracle 11g), than I get a result containing the expected ContextParameterValues.

When I **change** the Criteria query and set the join type for the condition.comparisonValues alias to **LEFT_JOIN**, than I do get the ContextParameterValues:

[image]

I diff compared the queries generated for both the INNER_JOIN and LEFT_JOIN contextParameterValues and the only difference is, as one might expect, the inner/outer join for the ContextParameterValue collection.

[image]

Also, BOTH queries give me the exact same result when I run them against the database myself (again, as expected).

So somehow it seems Hibernate has the data it needs to create the comparisonValues collection, independt of INNER_JOIN or LEFT_JOIN, but it only decides to create the comparisonValues collection when I specify LEFT_JOIN.

How can this be? I must be overseeing something here, or it is a Hibernate quirk/bug.